# How to cancel FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback after authenticating?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

When I get this error code [FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager#FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT) I must wait 30 seconds to retry again but after 30 seconds when trying to put my finger again nothing will happen why? And can I cancel FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback after authenticating? Because I want to re-authenticate after getting the error code above.

**Code**

```
FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback authenticationCallback = new FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, CharSequence errString) {
        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
        Log.w("ABC", "101 - " + errorCode + " - " + errString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
        super.onAuthenticationFailed();
        Log.w("ABC", "102");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpCode, CharSequence helpString) {
        super.onAuthenticationHelp(helpCode, helpString);
        Log.w("ABC", "103 - " + helpCode + " - " + helpString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
        Log.w("ABC", "104");
    }
};
fingerprintManager.authenticate(null, null, 0, authenticationCallback, null);
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Note that if you receive `onAuthenticationError` then no further calls will be made to that `AuthenticationCallback` instance. Have you tried making another `authenticate` call after 30 seconds?

Comment: @Michael I thought if I receive any error on `onAuthenticationError` the `AuthenticationCallback` will still working but I was wrong, I knew that now from you, Thanks for the information, But it's so weird because Google doesn't talk about that in their documentation.

Comment: @Michael No, I did not try to make another `authenticate` after 30 seconds and I'll try now but is there any way to know which time is left before try again or should I create it by myself and compare it using `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: _"Google doesn't talk about that in their documentation"_. It's mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback#onAuthenticationError(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)). As far as the 30 seconds go, you'll probably have to keep track of them yourself.

Comment: @Michael Nice, Sorry Google because I wronged you :), Now everything is clear for me but about my previous comment, Is it a good way to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to know which time is left before the next trying or there is a better method?